# numpy where output - how can I use the value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tuples

I have a list `some_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 6]]`
I want to find some index where expression was evaluated as true:

```
np.where([3 in sublist for sublist in some_list])
```

The output is `(array([1, 2], dtype=int64),)`.

Since I'd like to remove sublist with `3` inside, how can I access such array (in an elegant way)? With the array I can do `[some_list.pop(index) for index in array]`.

Edit: seems like it works using `for index in np.where([3 in sublist for sublist in some_list])[0]`

Comment: [a for a in some_list if not 3 in a]

Comment: Or `arr[~(arr==3).any(1)]` Or if you have to use `where`, `np.delete(some_list, np.where([3 in sublist for sublist in some_list]), 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` just returns a **tuple of arrays** that index where the element values True.

```
In [447]: some_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 6]]
```

Your list test:

```
In [448]: [3 in sublist for sublist in some_list]                               
Out[448]: [False, True, True]
In [449]: np.where([3 in sublist for sublist in some_list])                     
Out[449]: (array([1, 2]),)
```

That's a one element tuple, for a 1 dimensional list [448].  We can extract that array with simple indexing:

```
In [450]: _[0]                                                                  
Out[450]: array([1, 2])
```

and use it to select sublists from `some_list`:

```
In [451]: [some_list[i] for i in _]                                             
Out[451]: [[3, 4], [3, 6]]
```

If the list was an array:

```
In [455]: arr = np.array(some_list)                                             
In [456]: arr                                                                   
Out[456]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 6]])
```

we could do the same search for 3 with:

```
In [457]: arr==3                                                                
Out[457]: 
array([[False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False]])
In [458]: (arr==3).any(axis=1)                                                  
Out[458]: array([False,  True,  True])
In [459]: np.where(_)                                                           
Out[459]: (array([1, 2]),)
```

That [459] tuple can be used to index the [458] array directly.  In this case it can also be used to index rows of `arr`:

```
In [460]: arr[_]                                                                
Out[460]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [3, 6]])
```

Here that tuple derived from 1d [458] works, but if it didn't we could (again) extract the array with indexing, and use that:

```
In [461]: np.where((arr==3).any(axis=1))[0]                                     
Out[461]: array([1, 2])
In [462]: arr[_, :]                                                             
Out[462]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [3, 6]])
```

===

A pure-list way of doing this:

```
In [476]: [i for i,sublist in enumerate(some_list) if 3 in sublist]                     
Out[476]: [1, 2]
```

It could well be faster, since `np.where` converts list inputs to arrays, and that takes time.

Comment: Wow, I love the pure list! Thanks a lot for the time you spent. I had figured the first one but the full list is just pure beauty.